# How would I render a nodes comments in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm doing the following to load and render a node via ajax:

```
$node = node_load($id);
$node_view = node_view($node);
drupal_render($node_view);
```

This works perfectly for displaying the node, BUT the comments and comment form are missing. How would I add the comments and comment form to either $node or $node_view so they are rendered by drupal_render? node.tpl.php is being called to render the node FYI ;)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the comment module (specifically `comment_node_view()`) it should be added by default but if not this should work:

```
$node = node_load($id);
$node_view = node_view($node);

$node_view['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);

echo drupal_render($node_view);
```

Comment: This blog post was awesome too! http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/moving-comments-block-drupal-7